# Understanding How A Cookie String is Being Split

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have a javascript cookie on my site and I've come across some code that identifies if the `CookieConsent = true` cookie has been placed after a cookie banner is clicked to accept cookies.

I came across the code below that checks to see if the Cookie Consent does equal true, and by the looks of it, it is checking to see if there is any text after the `CookieConsent=` part of the cookie string?

I have no idea how this is working though.

The bits that I do understand are:

- the split() method splits the cookie string and separates 'true' from the rest of the string.
- the trim() method removes whitespace either side of what has been split

But how does the `.indexOf('CookieConsent=') == 0 }).length)` part of this code work.

Any explanation would be hugely appreciated.

```js
if (document.cookie.split(';').filter(function(item) {
      return item.trim().indexOf('CookieConsent=') == 0
      }).length) {
                    
   // prevents cookie notice showing on next visit by adding a class to hide the cookie banner
   cookieBanner.classList.add('hidden');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `filter()` function returns an array of all the elements of the original array that match a condition. In this case, the original array is the one that results from splitting the `document.cookie` at `;` delimiters.

`item.trim().indexOf('CookieConsent=')` returns the position of the string of `CookieConsent=`.

`== 0` tests whether that position is `0`, so it's testing whether the string begins with `CookieConsent=`.

Thus, the `filter()` call returns an array of all the cookies that begin with `CookieConsent=`.

`.length` returns the length of this filtered array. It will be 0 if no such cookies were found, non-zero if there were any.

Any non-zero number is truthy, so the `if` condition will succeed if a `CookieConsent` cookie was found.